# printing an ePub

Tags: epub, calibre, conversion

I know it's funny, but I would like to print some booklets I have. They are in ePub format without DRM, and my idea is to create a booklet in A6 format (they are not very long, otherwise I would not print them!)

Which suggestions do you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of **converting** with Calibre, you can directly **print** from the Calibre book viewer¹ and use a (virtual) printer driver that supports booklets construction on the fly.

On Windows and OSX these are more common. If you are on Linux you can easily create by installing CUPS, `impose+`, `psutils` and [a few lines of code for the backend](http://www.singularity.be/2012/01/side-project-booklet-printing-in-ubuntu.html)

¹ <sub>At least from the viewer included in Calibre version 1.17, probably earlier</sub>

Comment: printing to a virtual printer is probably the best option, I agree!

Answer (score 5):

The option which came into my mind is to convert it in PDF with Calibre and then print it. This has however the disadvantage of adding a new passage, and besides it is also necessary to set up the page size and to find an application which puts all the pages in the right position.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the task of the printer driver to arrange the pages for a booklet?

Answer (score 5):

This may not be the optimal approach, but it will work. You can unzip the epub and then pull out the html/xhtml files and printing those directly from your web browser.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use Calibre to convert, and if you have windows on your PC.  I would convert to [RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format).  You can easily open the RTF with MS Word or LibreOffice Write, make any minor changes that might be needed and print.